# Exclude user from search in sequelizejs

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I use "sequelize" and PostgreSQL in my application. I need to find all users and I use "findAll", but how can I exclude a user with id = 1. For example, "Find everyone except user with id = 1"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go , you can do this by using `Op.ne` :

```
User.findAll({
  where: {
    id : {
      [Op.ne]: 1
    }
  }
});
```

I think you should **[READ THIS](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html)** , this will help you alot for future queries.